# Reset after certain time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I'm wondering how to reset a function after say 5 seconds.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Now you 've learnt some JavaScript.";
}
document.getElementById('demo1').reset()
```

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1">1st Lesson</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

As you can see, I've used `.reset` but a) it doesn't work and b) don't know how to assign timing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to reset your #demo1 element's innerHTML after 5 seconds? Ok...
To do that, use this JavaScript code:

```js
function myFunction() {  
   const demo = document.getElementById("demo1");
   const initialText = demo.innerText;
   demo.innerText = "Now you've learnt some JavaScript.";

   setTimeout(() => {
    demo.innerText = initialText;
   }, 5000);
}
```

```css
p {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo1">1st Lesson</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Here, setTimeout is something that you need to do something after some desired time. 
(5000ms = 5s)

Comment: @PatMan10 Thanks for the edit. 
So, I need to make some html comment before writing code to have this "Run code snippet" feature right?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes those "html" like comments format the code to it can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the [reset() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) only works on form elements (for example, a text input or checkbox.) In fact, the reset method doesn't exist for a `<p>` element, so your code probably results in an error (check the browser dev console for the error message.)

To fix this, change element `demo1` to a form input element (you may also have to add a [default value attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp)).

Alternatively, you can change the way you "reset" the value. Just manually set the contents of the `<p>` back to the original value.

Finally use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to delay execution. Here is code that accomplishes your goal. (Hit the blue "Run code snippet" button to try it out!)

```js
function myFunction() {  
    // Save the HTML to "reset" later
    originalInnerHTML = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Now you've learnt some JavaScript.";
      
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Instead of
        // document.getElementById ('demo1').reset()
        // do this:
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = originalInnerHTML;
    }, 5000);
    
}
```

```css
P { background-color:red; } 

button {background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<p id="demo1">1st Lesson</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```