# Reset after defined time to original state

Tags: javascript

I have this code that I'd like to reset after 3 seconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <script>
            function bla() {
                document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = " to bla bla.";
            }
    
            document.getElementById('bla').reset()
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>A Web Page</h1>
        <p id="bla">From bla bla
        </p>
        <button type="button" onclick="bla()">Press </button>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

I have this

```
document.getElementById
('bla').reset()
```

But not sure how to implement it with a specific time period reset.

Comment: use setTimeout(reset, 3000)

Comment: setTimeout work. what did you try ?

Comment: Very similar to [Reset after certain time JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347081/reset-after-certain-time-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
function bla() {
    let x = document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = " to bla bla.";

    setTimeout(function () {
      document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML = x;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `setTimeout` function, you need to specify the code to "reset" your element. For example, if you want to remove the text inside of the DOM element, you would do something like the following

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = ''; // remove text in "#bla"
}, 2000); // reset element after 2 seconds
```

Overall, I think it would make things easier for people to answer your question if you specify exactly what you mean by "reset".

**updated answer**: If you want to restore text to its original value, you need to store the original value in a variable. Something like the following:

```
var originalState = " to bla bla."
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML = originalState; // restore to original state
}, 2000); // trigger after 2000 milliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Get to back to its original state. Your code seems to restore to no text at all, rather than original text.

Comment: @Amg I updated my answer. Basically, you need to store the original state in some sort of variable / data structure. Then you access the original state and update the DOM in the `setTimeout` function

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   // the function the want to call after timeout
}, 3000);
```

3000 is the time in millisecond, so 3 seconds

Comment: @Amg you have to provide the code which you want to execute inside the callback function as commented by Alainlb

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, and it's better to put your scripts in the last of the body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        
        <head>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <h1>A Web Page</h1>
            <p id="bla">From bla bla
            </p>
            <button type="button" onclick="bla()">Press </button>
        
            <script>
                var element = document.getElementById('bla');
        
                function bla() {
                    element.innerHTML = " to bla bla.";
                }
        
                function reset() {
                    element.innerHTML = "";
                }
        
                setTimeout(reset, 3000);
            </script>
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

write your Script as:

```
    <script>
            function bla() {
                    document.getElementById("bla").innerHTML = " to bla bla.";

                    setTimeout (function()
                            {
                               document.getElementById('bla').innerHTML = "";
                            },3000);
                    }
    </script>
```